# RabbitMQ - getting startup errors after enabling rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

I had RabbitMQ 3.9.11 running perfectly fine with SSL (not client authentication using certificates).

Next I enabled the rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl plugin and modified the advanced config file.
advanced.config:

```
[
 {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {auth_mechanisms, ['EXTERNAL', 'PLAIN']},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/ca_certificate.pem"},
                    {certfile,   "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/server/server_certificate.pem"},
                    {keyfile,    "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/server/private_key.pem"},
                    {verify,     verify_peer},
                    {ssl_cert_login_from, common_name},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true},
                    {depth, 2}
                    ]}
   ]}
].
```

Now I am seeing the following errors each time the RMQ server starts:

```
2023-12-16 02:08:20.334000+05:30 [info] <0.223.0>  Starting RabbitMQ 3.9.11 on Erlang 24.1.7 [jit]
....
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.271000+05:30 [info] <0.559.0> Statistics database started.
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.272000+05:30 [info] <0.558.0> Starting worker pool 'management_worker_pool' with 3 processes in it
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.273000+05:30 [info] <0.472.0> Ready to start client connection listeners
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.277000+05:30 [info] <0.602.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.280000+05:30 [info] <0.620.0> started TCP listener on 0.0.0.0:5672
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>     supervisor: {<0.624.0>,ranch_listener_sup}
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>     errorContext: start_error
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>     reason: badarg
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                {id,ranch_acceptors_sup},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                {mfargs,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                    {ranch_acceptors_sup,start_link,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                        [{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5671},ranch_ssl,logger]}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                {restart_type,permanent},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                {significant,false},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                {shutdown,infinity},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0>                {child_type,supervisor}]
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.624.0> 
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>   crasher:
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     initial call: supervisor:ranch_acceptors_sup/1
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     pid: <0.627.0>
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     registered_name: []
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     exception exit: badarg
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in function  inet6_tcp:listen/2 (inet6_tcp.erl, line 148)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in call from tls_socket:listen/3 (tls_socket.erl, line 79)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in call from ssl:listen/2 (ssl.erl, line 631)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in call from ranch_acceptors_sup:start_listen_socket/4 (src/ranch_acceptors_sup.erl, line 73)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in call from ranch_acceptors_sup:start_listen_sockets/5 (src/ranch_acceptors_sup.erl, line 54)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in call from ranch_acceptors_sup:init/1 (src/ranch_acceptors_sup.erl, line 34)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in call from supervisor:init/1 (supervisor.erl, line 330)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>       in call from gen_server:init_it/2 (gen_server.erl, line 423)
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     ancestors: [<0.624.0>,<0.622.0>,<0.621.0>,rabbit_sup,<0.223.0>]
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     message_queue_len: 0
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     messages: []
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     links: [<0.624.0>]
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     dictionary: []
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     trap_exit: true
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     status: running
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     heap_size: 6772
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     stack_size: 29
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>     reductions: 17351
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0>   neighbours:
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.627.0> 
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>     supervisor: {<0.622.0>,ranch_embedded_sup}
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>     errorContext: start_error
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>     reason: {shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,badarg}}
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                {id,{ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5671}}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                {mfargs,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                    {ranch_listener_sup,start_link,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                        [{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5671},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                         ranch_ssl,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                         #{connection_type => supervisor,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                           handshake_timeout => 5000,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                           max_connections => infinity,num_acceptors => 10,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                           num_conns_sups => 1,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                           socket_opts =>
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                               [{ip,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {port,5671},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                inet6,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {backlog,128},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {nodelay,true},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {linger,{true,0}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {exit_on_close,false},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {versions,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                    ['tlsv1.3','tlsv1.2','tlsv1.1',tlsv1]},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {cacertfile,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                    "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/ca_certificate.pem"},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {certfile,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                    "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/server/server_certificate.pem"},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {keyfile,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                    "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/server/private_key.pem"},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {verify,verify_peer},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {ssl_cert_login_from,common_name},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {fail_if_no_peer_cert,true},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                                {depth,2}]},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                         rabbit_connection_sup,[]]}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                {restart_type,permanent},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                {significant,false},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                {shutdown,infinity},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0>                {child_type,supervisor}]
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.283000+05:30 [error] <0.622.0> 
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>     supervisor: {<0.621.0>,tcp_listener_sup}
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>     errorContext: start_error
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>     reason: {shutdown,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                 {failed_to_start_child,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                     {ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5671}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                     {shutdown,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                         {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,badarg}}}}
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                {id,{ranch_embedded_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5671}}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                {mfargs,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                    {ranch_embedded_sup,start_link,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                        [{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5671},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                         ranch_ssl,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                         #{connection_type => supervisor,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                           handshake_timeout => 5000,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                           max_connections => infinity,num_acceptors => 10,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                           num_conns_sups => 1,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                           socket_opts =>
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                               [{ip,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {port,5671},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                inet6,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {backlog,128},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {nodelay,true},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {linger,{true,0}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {exit_on_close,false},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {versions,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                    ['tlsv1.3','tlsv1.2','tlsv1.1',tlsv1]},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {cacertfile,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                    "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/ca_certificate.pem"},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {certfile,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                    "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/server/server_certificate.pem"},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {keyfile,
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                    "C:/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-320/testca/server/private_key.pem"},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {verify,verify_peer},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {ssl_cert_login_from,common_name},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {fail_if_no_peer_cert,true},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                                {depth,2}]},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                         rabbit_connection_sup,[]]}},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                {restart_type,permanent},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                {significant,false},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                {shutdown,infinity},
    2023-12-16 02:08:22.284000+05:30 [error] <0.621.0>                {child_type,supervisor}]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!